# RavenDb - How can I save changes to multiple document sessions in one transaction?

Tags: ravendb, transactionscope

Within a single transaction scope, I am trying to save data to two separate Raven databases (on the same Raven server).

However, changes in the second session are not being saved to the server.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8081/" };

documentStore.Initialize();

documentStore.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists("database1");
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists("database2");

using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    using (var session1 = documentStore.OpenSession("database1"))
    {
        session1.Store(new Entity {Id = "1"});
        session1.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var session2 = documentStore.OpenSession("database2"))
    {
        session2.Store(new Entity {Id = "2"});
        session2.SaveChanges();
    }

    ts.Complete();
}
```

I can see changes in `session1` being saved to `database1` but changes in `session2` are not saved to `database2`. I've tried with RavenDb build 992 and build 2360

According to the Raven documentation, transactions across databases are  supported.

How can I get changes from `session2` to be committed?

Comment: This *should* work.  Does it work if you don't specify RequiresNew?

Comment: I've tried not specifying a `TransactionScopeOption` as well as TransactionScopeOption.Required but they all produce the same result - no changes in `database2`..

Comment: It seems I can only commit the second change if I suppress the transaction for the second session. i.e. by wrapping `session2` in a `new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)` but this defeats the purpose of having a transaction

Comment: Are you doing this in a unit test? I was able to reproduce your result, but *only* when I immediately checked programmatically.  If I sleep for as little as 10ms before checking, then it works.  Perhaps the distribute transaction needs time to commit?

Comment: I found the issue, and its by design.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distributed transaction needs time to commit.  You can either wait briefly with `Thread.Sleep` before checking your result, or you can set a special property in the session that is checking the result:

```
session.Advanced.AllowNonAuthoritativeInformation = false;
```

This seems like a bug, but it is actually by design.  Read [Working with System.Transactions](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/faq/working-with-dtc) in the RavenDB documentation.

(FYI - I didn't know this either until I checked.)

Comment: Thanks Matt, it does appear to be a timing issue. I was running my sample code in a Console app which was exiting before the transaction had time to commit on the second database. If I sleep 100ms before exiting, I can then see the data in `database2` in Raven Studio (build  2360)

Comment: It does appear to be a bug in Raven build 992 as no matter how long I Thread.Sleep for, the transaction is never committed on the second database. Thread.Sleep only seems to work on the later versions of RavenDb (e.g. build 2360)